# use threshold on a list of numbers to subset corresponding elements from other list of objects

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I have two lists of lists which share the same dimension (same length, each list in the list have the same number of elements)

list1 looks like this:

```
list1 = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[4,5,2],[4,0,9]]
```

list2 looks like this:

```
list2 = [['a''b','c'],['a','d','e'],['a','f','b'],['p','o','a']]
```

let's say I have a threshold x = 3

I want to filter out elements from list 2 which have the same position of those elements in list1 which fall below x = 3

so for instance for x = 3 I would want to obtain:

```
list3 = [[],['e'],['a','f'],['p','a']
```

how can I do so?

thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zip` to walk the two lists (and sublists) together and filter the values in `list2` that satisfy the condition in the corresponding position in `list1`:

```
out = [[j for i, j in zip(li1, li2) if i>3] for li1, li2 in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Output:

```
[[], ['e'], ['a', 'f'], ['p', 'a']]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use the Python [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function to "merge" the two lists.

```py
list1 = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[4,5,2],[4,0,9]]
list2 = [['a','b','c'],['a','d','e'],['a','f','b'],['p','o','a']]

threshold = 3

list3 = [
    [char for value, char in zip(sub_one, sub_two) if value > threshold]
    for sub_one, sub_two in zip(list1, list2)
]

print(list3)
```

This outputs

```
[[], ['e'], ['a', 'f'], ['p', 'a']]
```

The outer `zip` merges `list1` and `list2` into:

```
[([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']),
 ([2, 3, 4], ['a', 'd', 'e']),
 ([4, 5, 2], ['a', 'f', 'b']),
 ([4, 0, 9], ['p', 'o', 'a'])]
```

while the inner `zip` merges e.g. `[1,2,3]` and `['a','b','c']` into `[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]`. Then, the inner list comprehension can use a simple filtering with `if value > threshold`.